# Random items in Prolog

Tags: random, prolog, swi-prolog

I know I can do `X is random(10).` to get a random number from 0 to 10, but is there a similar command to get a random matching item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement it. Here is a version:

```
%% choose(List, Elt) - chooses a random element
%% in List and unifies it with Elt.
choose([], []).
choose(List, Elt) :-
        length(List, Length),
        random(0, Length, Index),
        nth0(Index, List, Elt).
```

From http://ozone.wordpress.com/2006/02/22/little-prolog-challenge/

Comment: Whoa there, the first clause of choose/2 isn't what you want. If the list it empty you should produce no solutions instead of unifying Elt with the empty list. "choose([],_) :- !, fail." would fix it.

Also, this generates an infinite number of solutions which is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 7):

SWI-Prolog v6 has `random_member/2` defined like this:

```
?- listing(random_member).
random:random_member(D, A) :-
    length(A, B),
    C is random(B),
    nth0(C, A, D).
```

Usage example:

```
?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
N = 1.

?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
N = 1.

?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
N = 2.

?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
false.

?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
false.

?- random_member(a(N), [a(1), a(2), b(3)]).
N = 2.
```

You probably want to use it in the `(-,+)` mode though.