# Minimum distance between points

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have a matrix of N lines and N columns. Let's take N = 5. How can I make a .pl program which returns me a list of N random pairs in which the distance between any pair is minimum 2? A pair is of form (i, j), where i represents the line and j represents the column of an element. I made the distance function:

```
dist(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, D) :-  
    D is round(sqrt((X2 - X1)**2 + (Y2 - Y1)**2)).
```

The main should look like this:

```
?- L = []
?- make_list(L).
L = [pair(5,5), pair(1,1), pair(3, 3), pair(1,5), pair(5, 1)]
```

Can you give me any useful piece of code or at least some ideas?

Comment: First of all - how would you represent that matrix?

Comment: Sorry for omitting that ... I would hardcoded them, like this:  
matrix(1, 1).  
matrix(1, 2).  
..................  
matrix(5, 4).  
matrix(5, 5).

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how this representation will define a 5x5 matrix. It has to contain 25 values.

Comment: Eugene Sh., that's why I have put "...........", press this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/37j5TdPc) to see the full list

Comment: Brief, `matrix(X,Y) :- between(1,5,X), between(1,5,Y).`

Comment: Thank you @false, this would help me to not hardcode my matrix ... Now can you give me an idea on how to build my predicate in order to find 5 pairs that for any other pair the distance between those two is minimum 2?

Comment: `(X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 >= 2^2` is a better test

Comment: Still, I don't get what is `matrix(1,2)` ? Is it a first row / second column? So where is the value?

Comment: Indeed @false, you are right again. Eugene, I think I was a bit incomprehensible. Actually, I have to check if the distance of positions between two elements is minimum 2, not the distance of values between two elements is minimum 2 ...

Comment: There are many things left unspecified: How long should this list be? As long as possible? Can it contain cycles etc.

Comment: Oh. That makes more sense. In this case you don't even need to represent the matrix. It's dimensions would be enough

Comment: `step(pair(X1,Y1),pair(X2,Y2)) :- matrix(X1,Y1), matrix(X2,Y2),  X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 >= 2^2.` That's for sure. But what else?

Comment: Guys, sorry for being obscure, again. All I need is to create a list from 5 random pairs which complies the property described above ... Here I posted some code:  http://pastebin.com/Lc6zhqqa; @false, if I call find(X1, X2, X3, X4) from swi-prolog, it will give me an (X1, X2), (X3, X4) elements with the property described above ... If I press ; (semicolon) it will give me another one, and so forth ... This is not what I really need ... What I really need is a new predicate of arity 1 ( if possible ), which when I call it from swi-prolog, it will return me a list with 5 random (unique) pairs.

Comment: `?- step(P1,P2),step(P2,P3),step(P3,P4),step(P4,P5).`  However, this permits cycles. Add goals `dif(P1, P3), dif(P2, P4), ...` to avoid them

Comment: Yea, but actually this gives me only "true" as a result, not a list which contains the pairs with their positions ... 

EDIT: And one more thing, it never gives me random pairs, always the pairs are preserved as result ...

Comment: Oh no: Above query produces an answer `P1 = pair(...` for `P1, ... P5`. So the answer is not just `true`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following pseudocode

1. Obtain the list of all valid pairs - use e.g. `findall/3` with rules suggested in the comments :)
2. Compute the list length - use `lenght/2`
3. Choose random list item - described in [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261238/random-items-in-prolog)

This should work well :) give it a try, it's quite straightforward.